# How to remove grid from Plotly 3D plot?

Tags: plotly-python

I am using plotly in Python to plot a sphere. And I would like to know if it's possible to remove the grid and axes, everything but the sphere basically.
Additionnally, I would also like to have my three axes as just three arrows originating from the center of my sphere.

If it's not doable in Plotly, do you know of any alternative? Again, I am coding in Python.

Many thanks in advance

Antoine

[image]

```
    trace = [
            go.Surface(
                name='Map',
                x=tuple(x),
                y=tuple(y),
                z=tuple(z),
                colorscale='Viridis',
                surfacecolor=c_norm,
                hoverinfo='text',
                opacity=1
                ),
            go.Scatter3d(
                    name='Z1 source',
                    x=[z1_sources_coord[0,0]], 
                    y=[z1_sources_coord[0,1]], 
                    z=[z1_sources_coord[0,2]], 
                    mode='markers', 
                    marker=dict(size=3, color='red'),
                    opacity=1
                ),
            go.Scatter3d(
                    name='Z2 source',
                    x=z2_sources_coord[:,0], 
                    y=z2_sources_coord[:,1], 
                    z=z2_sources_coord[:,2], 
                    mode='markers', 
                    marker=dict(size=6, color='blue'),
                    opacity=1
                )
    ]

    fig=go.Figure(data=trace)
    fig.show()
```

Comment: what are the values of x,y,z?

Comment: x, y, z in the go.Surface are simply coordinates of the sphere points.

Comment: Your example is hard to reproduce